# Dropping in a list with no element in a list in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, user-interface

I am using the Jquery drag and drop feature shown [here](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists)

## HTML CODE

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
   <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
   <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
   <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
   <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

## JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
$(function() {
   $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
     connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
   }).disableSelection();
});
```

I made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ankur20us/55Sax/1)

Here everything is running fine but the only thing which is unusual is as any of the list goes empty it is removed or taken off from the DOM since, we are unable to add anything back into it, I want to do that, how can I do that, please shed some light.

Thanks in advance,
Ankur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the emptied `ul` has no `height` or `width` to capture the drag event. Set the following CSS and it works:

```
.connectedSortable {
    min-height: 50px;
    min-width: 120px;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/55Sax/2/)

Answer (score 2):

CSS

```
#sortable1, #sortable2 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 2.5em;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width:120px; // Add width HERE
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: "ul" // Change that
    }).disableSelection();
  });
```

I tested it in your fiddler and worked fine

Comment: Thanks Ricky..... Your answer worked but because Rory answered first, I am accepting his answer, but anyways +1 :)